# Append the image in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jquery plugin to toggle div on click.The toggle link contains the text "View" and "Close" but I'm wanted to replace that text with image icons

Jquery code for this

```
var defaults = {

        showText: 'View',
        hideText: 'Hide'
  };

 if(options.changeText==1){
         $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
```

how to give image link insteade of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var defaults = {

        show: '<img src="something.jpg"/>View',
        hide: '<img src="something.jpg"/>Hide'
};

if(options.changeText==1){
$(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.html(options.hide) : toggleClick.html(options.show);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be to toggle Class.  This way it's one line of code... Have a look at this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#toggleDiv").click(function () {
           $(this).find(".view").toggleClass("close")
        });
    });

</script>
<style>
    .view {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
        width:30px;
        height:30px;
        background-image:url(../styles/play.png);
        background-size:100% 100%;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    .close {
        background-image:url(../styles/pause.png);
    }
    #toggleDiv{
        position:relative ;
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        height:200px;
        width:400px;
    }
</style>
<div id="toggleDiv" class="up">
    <div class="view"></div>
</div>
```